# Update o column values by another column values IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in mysql with the following colunms: {id, tnid, exp}.

I would like to replace `tnid` values with `id` values.

How to handle this UPDATE QUERY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but this should do it:

```
UPDATE the_table
  SET tnid = id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically...

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET tnid = id;
```

...should do the job.

I recommend to get a little bit more familiar with the basics of SQL, p.e. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp) is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I have sql background from university and  I can suggest you to try this.maybe it works

Update Xtable set Xtable.tnid = Xtable.id
WHERE 1=1